# c# DataTable - working out percentages, even for records which don't exist

Tags: c#, datatable, aggregate-functions

I hope folks can help me out with a problem I'm trying to solve. It's really baffled me:

I have a C# datatable, with for example, the following content:

```
LotNo   Level   IsValid?
123         2   Yes
123         2   Yes
123         2   Yes
123         3   Yes
123         3   No
123         3   Yes
456         2   Yes
456         2   No
456         2   No
456         2   No
456         3   Yes
890         1   No
890         1   No
```

The "**IsValid?**" column will only ever be "**Yes**" or "**No**". Whereas the **LotNo** and **Level** columns are always dynamic. Also the records aren't in any order (unlike the table above).

I'm trying to figure out the code to evaluate the percentage of records which have "**IsValid = Yes**" across the total of all records for that LotNo and Level.

So in the example above, I'm looking for the following output:

```
**LotNo Level   PctValid?** 
123     2       100     [ie 3 x Yes out of a total of 3 items for LotNo 123 and Level 2]
123     3       66.66   [ie 2 x Yes out of a total of 3 items for LotNo 123 and Level 3]
456     2       25      [ie 1 x Yes out of a total of 4 items for LotNo 123 and Level 2]
456     3       100     [ie 1 x Yes out of a total of 1 item for LotNo 456 and Level 3]
890     1       0       [ie zero x Yes out of a total of 2 items for LotNo 890 and Level 1]
```

What I'm finding particularly difficult is coping with the instance where there are *no* records - for example, LotNo=890 and Level=1 has no records where "IsValid=Yes". I know I sort of need a kind SQL "outer-join" effect. I also need some kind of SQL group by - not to sure how this applies with a DataTable.

I've tried breaking it down into "for" loops, and creating a new records when the loop encounters a new batch number, but it quickly descends into madness trying to cope with the dynamic number of levels.

I hope I've phrased this question okay - I'm not a regular poster.

Any pointers on where on earth to start? I'm baffled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setup:

```
 var dt = new DataTable();

 dt.Columns.Add("LotNo", typeof(int));
 dt.Columns.Add("Level", typeof(int));
 dt.Columns.Add("IsValid", typeof(string));

 dt.Rows.Add(123, 2, true);
 dt.Rows.Add(123, 2, true);
 dt.Rows.Add(123, 2, true);
 dt.Rows.Add(123, 3, true);
 dt.Rows.Add(123, 3, false);
 dt.Rows.Add(123, 3, true);

 dt.Rows.Add(456, 2, true);
 dt.Rows.Add(456, 2, false);
 dt.Rows.Add(456, 2, false);
 dt.Rows.Add(456, 2, false)
 dt.Rows.Add(456, 3, true);

 dt.Rows.Add(890, 1, false);
 dt.Rows.Add(890, 1, false);
```

then just use LINQ:

```
 ar results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(r => new
                          {
                               LotNo = r.Field<int>("LotNo"),
                               Level = r.Field<int>("Level"),
                               IsValid = r.Field<string>("IsValid")
                          })
                 .GroupBy(x => new
                          {
                               x.LotNo,
                               x.Level
                          })
                  .Select(g => new
                          {
                               g.Key.LotNo,
                               g.Key.Level,
                               Average = (double) g.Count(x => x.IsValid.ToLower() == "true")/g.Count()
                          });


  foreach (var result in results)
  {
      Console.WriteLine($"{result.Level}-{result.LotNo} : {result.Average * 100}");
  }
```

Output:

```
>123-2 : 100
>123-3 : 66.6666666666667
>456-2 : 25
>456-3 : 100
>890-1 : 0
```

Comment: Bravo, Jonesopolis! That's beautifully elegant and works marvellously. Great work!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I believe that's what you're looking for:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("LotNo", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Level", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("IsValid", typeof(string));

        dt.Rows.Add(123, 2, "Yes");
        dt.Rows.Add(123, 2, "Yes");
        dt.Rows.Add(123, 2, "Yes");
        dt.Rows.Add(123, 3, "Yes");
        dt.Rows.Add(123, 3, "No");
        dt.Rows.Add(123, 3, "Yes");
        dt.Rows.Add(456, 2, "Yes");
        dt.Rows.Add(456, 2, "No");
        dt.Rows.Add(456, 2, "No");
        dt.Rows.Add(456, 2, "No");
        dt.Rows.Add(456, 3, "Yes");
        dt.Rows.Add(890, 1, "No");
        dt.Rows.Add(890, 1, "No");


        var stat = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(g => new
            {
                LotNo = g.Field<int>("LotNo"),
                Level = g.Field<int>("Level"),
                IsValid = g.Field<string>("IsValid")
            })
            .Select(s => new
            {
                LotNo = s.Key.LotNo,
                Level = s.Key.Level,
                IsValid = s.Key.IsValid,
                Count = s.Count()
            });
```

stat variable contains all the info as specified in the select function.

Comment: by the way, for calculating the percentage i think you have to do a join with a similar query with group on only the LotNo, Level to have a total per Isvalid. and then you could calculate the field in a subsequent query. I would do that but i'm too lazy to be honest with you :)